# <p:spinner> Não aceita double

Tags: primefaces, spinners

Gente, boa noite.

Estou usando o Primefaces 5.0 e estou com um problema no componente .

Todas as vezes que tento colocar um valor de ponto flutuante nele (25.43, por exemplo) ele muda apenas para a parte inteira do valor (25).

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

```
<p:column><h:outputLabel for="ir" value="Imposto de Renda: " class="componentePF label"/></p:column>
<p:column><p:spinner id="ir" value="#{cenarioBean.tributosParametros.ir}" class="componentePF text"/></p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.

No trecho de código que você colocou não tem o spinner que é o título do seu tópico.

Segundo essa documentação o componente aceita **double** http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/spinner.xhtml

Está sentando corretamente o value da view?

Comment: Erick, obrigado pela observação de olhar o showcase. Vi agora que eu poderia usar o stepFactor pra ele manter o valor com vírgula (ponto, no caso).